# ga:landingPagePath Issue

Tags: google-analytics-api

I need help getting the landingpage for a session using google analytics ga:landingPagePath.

When i use the query below I get the correct result with my first visit using IE. However, when I close IE and open Firefox and visit a different landing page, I still get the landing page of the previous session. I should get the landing page of the current firefox session unless since this is a new browser session. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    // query google analytics
    var query1 = new Google.GData.Analytics.DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);
    query1.Ids = string.Format("ga:{0}", profileId);
    query1.Metrics = "ga:entrances";
    query1.Dimensions = "ga:landingPagePath";
    //query1.Filters = "ga:entrances==1";


    //query.Filters = string.Format("ga:pagePath=={0}", url);


    // set from and to date (google does not accept datetime min/max value)
    string fromDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    query1.GAStartDate = fromDate;
    query1.GAEndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    var dataFeed = service.Query(query1);
    if (dataFeed != null && dataFeed.Entries != null && dataFeed.Entries.Count > 0)
    {
        var dataEntries = dataFeed.Entries.Last() as Google.GData.Analytics.DataEntry;
        var landingPage = dataEntries;
        result = landingPage.Dimensions.Last().Value.ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["landing"] = result.ToString();

    }
    return result;
}
```